# UINavigationController Automatic Back Button Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

[image: StoryboardProblem]

I cannot tell any difference between the push segues going to the top view controller and the segues going to the bottom view controller.

The bottom view controller has a back button labeled "iFLY2" automatically on the left side of the navigation bar, and works perfectly. However, the top view controller has a "Main Menu" button just like the table view controller which crashes the app. Why is this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Are you only possibly pushing to 2 views? If so, you may want to get rid of the confusing looking set of segues and just make the pushes programmatically.

Comment: I am only pushing two views, but in order to have the pushed view controller tell which button was pressed, I'm using the segue's identifier. I feel like this is not such a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. The problem was due to me trying to pop the view controller on top in viewwillappear, which will cause issues with the navigation bar.